# "Conforms to" stands for in Iphone terminology?

Tags: iphone

What does "conform to" means in IPhone Development? This word is extensively used but I can't find a satisfactory definition of it.

Let's say If we have 3 classes - A,B & C

If A inherits B 
& 
If A conforms to C

What does that means?

Also, Why does most classes,protocols conforms to NSObject.

Comment: *conforming to* a protocol is analogous to *implementing* an interface in Java/C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, C would have to be a protocol.  Protocols are just a lists of method signatures.

If A conforms to C, it means it implements all the methods listed in the protocol (ie method bodies are provided for each of the method signatures defined in the protocol.)

Since A also inherits from B, A does does not have to explicitly implement methods that B has already implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the lucid explanation. Much Appreciated.

Thanks 
Anuj

Answer (score 0):

Means class has the necessary methods to make it compliant to the given protocol . you can read about objective c protocols [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-SW1)